# Which original character was Kramer's stuttering inspired from?

Tags: character, seinfeld

[Kramer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmo_Kramer) from *Seinfeld* makes very peculiar sounds whenever he is amused or surprised. The sound seems like kinda stuttering/stammering.

This sound was inspired from another character from an old TV show/movie. I vaguely remember it was mentioned in the commentary/interview by someone. I think I had watched it on DVD.

Any idea which character was the inspiration for those peculiar sounds made by Kramer?

Here are those sounds (1:04 to 1:10):

Comment: I don't know the specific person you're thinking of since I haven't heard the commentary and humorous vocalizations must go back to the beginning of performance. I know Michael Richards has been doing sound effects for a long time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIUxoytpcxE and I'm reminded of Stan Laurel (though I can't find a good clip). There's also this great Victor Borge bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf_TDuhk3No

Comment: Hey. Thanks for those links. Pretty rare. :-) I answered the question by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found  it.

The sounds were inspired by the character Margie Albright of a very old sitcom [My Little Margie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044283/). The character Margie was played by [Gale Storm](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0832561/?ref_=tt_cl_t1).

[image]

Michael Richards mentioned this in the extras of 3rd season.